# Working with arrays with the SQLite/json1 extension (append, tail)

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-json1

The json1 extension of sqlite3 allows querying and manipulating JSON-values (stored TEXT fields). I want to append a new element to a JSON-array residing inside some JSON-value (in a SQLite database).
Unfortunately the support for JSON-arrays seems to be sub-optimal when working with dynamically sized arrays (of unknown length).

I have a trivial table that stores JSON values.

```
CREATE TABLE T (DATA);
```

There would be JSON values in that table that consist of a JSON-array as root node, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO T VALUES(json_array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

To append to the array that is at path "$" (for simplicity), I can issue the following query:

```
UPDATE T SET DATA =
  (SELECT json_insert(DATA,
    '$[' || json_array_length(json_extract(DATA, '$')) || ']', 42));
```

This works but seems fairly horrible; I first `json_extract` the array, then compute it's length. This length is then concatenated into a new JSON-path expression which is then fed back into the `json_insert` to find the right spot.
Getting the last element can be done the same way:

```
SELECT json_extract(DATA,
  '$[' || (json_array_length(json_extract(DATA, '$')) - 1) || ']')
FROM T;
```

This seems pretty cumbersome. I hoped for something like a `$[-1]` path but this does not seem to be supported.
Can this be solved in a more elegant way in SQLite?

Comment: I ran into this question in my own quest to resolve exactly this issue.  I can only confirm your observation - the JSON array support in SQLite JSON1 is not quite there yet.  It would be so much nicer if there were a `json_append` function to simply add a new element to an existing JSON array.  A tip if you are still playing with SQLite JSON - using in memory tables as temporary stores makes it a whole lot easier to perform complex JSON manipulation in SQLite without resorting to highly convoluted SQL one-liners.